Constructing a specific 2-variable function taking integer arguments whose value is odd/even only when arguments are equal
I find myself in need of a specific function for work related to a programming project. Suppose $x$ and $y$ are two positive integers satisfying $1 \leq x,y \leq K$ where $K \geq 2$ is an integer. I need to find two functions $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ such that:

$f(x)+g(y)$ is integer valued.
$f(x)+g(y)$ is an even integer only when $x=y$ and an odd integer otherwise, or vice versa, i.e. that $f(x)+g(y)$ is an odd integer only when $x=y$ and an even integer otherwise.
Each of $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ does not need to be integer-valued in general; I know properties 1 and 2 cannot be satisfied for integer-valued functions $f$ and $g$. $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ can be complex valued.
Preferably functions that can be computed on a computer with floating/double-precision variables, or numerically approximated.

Are there such general closed-form functions $f$ and $g$? I do not really need closed-form functions as for my project, I am only considering $K \leq 500$, so perhaps an algorithm to find the functions' mappings. Perhaps there is a number-theoretic result or conjecture that holds for $K \leq 500$ that would allow this, or even for $K$ close to $500$ would be great. I do not actually know if such functions exist. I thank all helpers.

A minor point is regarding your statement of "I know properties 1 and 2 cannot be satisfied for integer-valued functions $f$ and $g$". This is correct for $K\ge 3$, but not for $K=2$. For that value of $K$, with the first possibility of $f(x)+f(y)$ being "an even integer only when $x=y$ and an odd integer otherwise", we can use $f(x)=x$ and $f(y)=y$, while for the second choice of "or vice versa, i.e. that $f(x)+g(y)$ is an odd integer only when $x=y$ and an even integer otherwise", we can instead use something like $f(x)=x$ and $f(y)=y+1$.

The title doesn't match the question: the title asks for a single function of two variables, but the question body asks for two functions each of a single variable.  (I suspect the question body is correct, as I think it'd be very easy to find a single function of two variables matching all the conditions.)

It won't work if $K \ge 3$. Consider any three distinct members $a,b,c$ of the domain of $f$ and $g$.
\begin{align}
&(f(a) + g(a)) + (f(b) + g(b)) + (f(c) + g(c))\\
=\,& (f(a) + g(b)) + (f(b) + g(c)) + (f(c) + g(a))\end{align}
But according to your condition (2.), one side is the sum of three odd integers (therefore odd) and the other side is the sum of three even integers (therefore even).
